# My custom module working fine in Magento 2 all version (2.1 to 2.3) expected 2.0 anyone has any idea?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**PHP version 5.6**

> Error: "There has been an error processing your request";

**I have checked the error log but it not show me any error.**

I have also cleared cache using below command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Anyone any idea regarding this?

Note:

```
$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Module_Name::index');
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Module List'))
```

I noticed this code is not working in Magento 2.0.0 version.

Comment: Not clear. Magento 2.0 and 2.1 version are quite different. Module might not be compatible.

Comment: I have not more idea about Magento custom module, but is there same way we implement a custom module in version 2.0 and 2.1 or it quite different? In index controller above explain the description code is not working and stop module to work.

Comment: check magento 2.0 php version compatiblity and also check your module's composer.json file is defined required php version for 2.0.0

Comment: any error in log file?